# Retrieve Code or PRE tag content on server side

Tags: javascript, c#, html, pre

I am trying to read the content of "PRE" or "CODE" tag of HTML to server side in C#.
I am using HTML editor "tinymce". Preview is displayed properly. But when I read it on server side in string variable and the display it in some div.
Then all the formatting is lost and code is shown in single line.

```
<pre>
  <code>
    function Panel(element, canClose, closeHandler) {
        this.element = element;
        this.canClose = canClose;
        this.closeHandler = function() {
            if (closeHandler) closeHandler()
        };
    }

  </code>

</pre>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: My code is simple.. i am unable to post the code here. it is not formatting properly

<pre><code>function Panel(element, canClose, closeHandler) {
  this.element = element;
  this.canClose = canClose;
  this.closeHandler = function () { if (closeHandler) closeHandler() };
}</code></pre>

Comment: Can you also post what you are using to read in the tags? Thanks!

Comment: I am using c# code to read the html, the i have to save it in database and then retrieve it and display in div.
 
string s = tbxTinymce.Text;
divOutput.InnerHtml = s;

But when i assign it to div.. all the code is in single line. Formatting is lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `<pre>...</pre>` tags to denote preformatted text, simply embedding in `<div>...</div>` tags will ignore all newlines unless you use `<br />` to force a new line break

For example, to embed the string in pre tags, you may use:

```
string s = tbxTinymce.Text;
s = "<pre>" + s + "</pre>";
divOutput.InnerHtml = s;
```

Comment: Is there a way, that i dont want to use explicitly <br/> tag.
Suppose i copy some code from Class and paste it in html editor inside PRE tag and then save it in a string variable and then display it in Div?

Comment: That is exactly what the example is doing, it uses your code but embeds the string in pre tags

Comment: yes i tested it, but it is showing the in single line, i dont want to use <br/> tag

Comment: Is tbxTinymce set up as a multiline or a singleline text box?

Comment: Thanks.. by setting multiline, it worked fine.
Is there any way to highlight the code accordingly. Just like the stack overflow is highlighting our code block?

Comment: You can add a library e.g. https://highlightjs.org/usage/ to automatically highlight anything in a code block